# Having problems login into Gmail imaps (not using javamail) tag error

Tags: java, authentication, gmail

I am trying to create a typestate client program in java that speaks to the gimaps but I am having trouble getting it to login in. When I enter my details it sends back * BAD invalid tag. I presume this is something to do with the tag that I am sending. Here's the code then I'll explain more.

```
     public class CMain  {
        static final String CRLF = "\r\n";
        public static String safeRead(BufferedReader readerC) {
        String readline = "";
        try {
            readline = readerC.readLine();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Input/Output error, unable to read");
            System.exit(+1);
        }
        return readline;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CRole currentC = new CRole();
        BufferedReader readerC = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("connecting: ");

        String payload2 = currentC.receive_acceptedStringFromS();
        System.out.println("Received from S: " + payload2);
        //connected - now decide if you want to login
        System.out.print("Choose a label among [LOGIN, QUIT]: ");
        String label1 = safeRead(readerC).equals("LOGIN") ? "1" : "2";


        switch(currentC.send_Choice1LabelToS(label1).getEnum()){
            case Choice1.LOGIN:
            System.out.print("Send to S: ");
            //When i get here I enter username@gmail.com password
            String payload3 = safeRead(readerC);
            currentC.send_loginStringToS(payload3);
            String response = currentC.receive_Choice2LabelFromS();
            System.out.println("Server: " + response);

            String payload4 = currentC.receive_OKStringFromS();
            System.out.println("Received from S: " + payload4);
            System.out.print("Choose a label among [INBOX, QUIT]: ");
            String label2 = safeRead(readerC).equals("INBOX") ? "1" : "2";
            switch(currentC.send_Choice3LabelToS(label2).getEnum()){
                case Choice3.INBOX:
                System.out.print("Send to S: ");
                String payload5 = safeRead(readerC);
                currentC.send_inboxStringToS(payload5); 
                break;
                case Choice3.QUIT:
                System.out.print("Send to S: ");
                String payload6 = safeRead(readerC);
                currentC.send_quitStringToS(payload6);
                break;
                }


        break;
        case Choice1.QUIT:
        System.out.print("Send to S: ");
        String payload8 = safeRead(readerC);
        currentC.send_quitStringToS(payload8);
        break;
        }
    }
}

    public class CRole  {
       private BufferedReader socketSIn = null;
       private PrintWriter socketSOut = null;
       private Socket client;
       public CRole(){
           SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        try {
            client = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket("imap.gmail.com", 993);
            System.out.println("Connect to Host");
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to listen on ports");
            System.exit(+1);
        }
        try {
            socketSIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            socketSOut = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Read failed");
            System.exit(+1);
        }
    }
    public void send_connectStringToS(String payload) {
        this.socketSOut.println(payload);
    }
    public String receive_acceptedStringFromS() {
        String line = "";
        try {
            line = this.socketSIn.readLine();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Input/Outpur error.");
            System.exit(+1);
        }
        return line;
    }
    public Choice1 send_Choice1LabelToS(String payload) {
        this.socketSOut.println(payload);
        int intLabelChoice1 = Integer.parseInt(payload);
        //int intLabelChoice1 = 1;
        switch(intLabelChoice1){
            case 1:
            return new Choice1(Choice1.LOGIN);
            case 2:
            default:
            return new Choice1(Choice1.QUIT);
        }
    }
    public void send_loginStringToS(String payload) {
        this.socketSOut.println(payload);
    }
    public String receive_Choice2LabelFromS() {
        String line = "";
        try {
            line = this.socketSIn.readLine();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Input/Outpur error.");
            System.exit(+1);
        }
        return line;
    }
    public String receive_OKStringFromS() {
        String line = "";
        try {
            line = this.socketSIn.readLine();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Input/Outpur error.");
            System.exit(+1);
        }
        return line;
    }
    public Choice3 send_Choice3LabelToS(String payload) {
        this.socketSOut.println(payload);
        int intLabelChoice3 = Integer.parseInt(payload);
        switch(intLabelChoice3){
            case 1:
            return new Choice3(Choice3.INBOX);
            case 2:
            default:
            return new Choice3(Choice3.QUIT);
        }
    }
    public void send_inboxStringToS(String payload) {
        this.socketSOut.println(payload);
    }
    public void send_quitStringToS(String payload) {
        this.socketSOut.println(payload);
    }
    public String receive_quitStringFromS() {
        String line = "";
        try {
            line = this.socketSIn.readLine();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Input/Outpur error.");
            System.exit(+1);
        }
        return line;
    }
}
```

So is it a case of the string that I am sending gmail? I have sent the following strings: username@gmail.com password; a001 login username@gmail.com password; a001 username@gmail.com password; username@gmail.com, password. And I have had no luck with these.

Or is it something to do with OAuth?

I am not using javamail and do not wish to use it.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Problem semi fixed. I rewrote a simple program not using the typestating method of programming and this work so it is not sending an incorrect tag but there is something in the typestated code that is causing the problems.